# pandas assign result from list of columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe as shown below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randn(5), 'B': np.zeros(5), 'C': np.zeros(5)})
df
>>>
          A    B    C
0  0.496714  0.0  0.0
1 -0.138264  0.0  0.0
2  0.647689  0.0  0.0
3  1.523030  0.0  0.0
4 -0.234153  0.0  0.0
```

And I have the list of columns which I want to populate with the value of 1, when `A` is negative.

```py
idx = df.A < 0
cols = ['B', 'C']
```

So in this case, **I want the indices [1, 'B'] and [4, 'C'] set to 1.**

### What I tried:

However, doing `df.loc[idx, cols] = 1` sets the entire row to be 1, and not just the individual column. I also tried doing `df.loc[idx, cols] = pd.get_dummies(cols)` which gave the result:

```
          A    B    C
0  0.496714  0.0  0.0
1 -0.138264  0.0  1.0
2  0.647689  0.0  0.0
3  1.523030  0.0  0.0
4 -0.234153  NaN  NaN
```

I'm assuming this is because the index of `get_dummies` and the dataframe don't line up.

### Expected Output:

```py
          A    B    C
0  0.496714  0.0  0.0
1 -0.138264  1.0  0.0
2  0.647689  0.0  0.0
3  1.523030  0.0  0.0
4 -0.234153  0.0  1.0
```

So what's the best (read fastest) way to do this. In my case, there are 1000's of rows and 5 columns.

### Timing of results:

TLDR: editing values directly is faster.

```py
%%timeit
df.values[idx, df.columns.get_indexer(cols)] = 1
```

123 µs ± 2.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

```py
%%timeit
df.iloc[idx.array,df.columns.get_indexer(cols)]=1
```

266 µs ± 7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: ```df.iloc[idx.array,df.columns.get_indexer(cols)]=1``` might do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy indexing for improve performance:

```
idx = df.A < 0
res = ['B', 'C']
arr = df.values
arr[idx, df.columns.get_indexer(res)] = 1
print (arr)
[[ 0.49671415  0.          0.        ]
 [-0.1382643   1.          0.        ]
 [ 0.64768854  0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.52302986  0.          0.        ]
 [-0.23415337  0.          1.        ]]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
print (df)
          A    B    C
0  0.496714  0.0  0.0
1 -0.138264  1.0  0.0
2  0.647689  0.0  0.0
3  1.523030  0.0  0.0
4 -0.234153  0.0  1.0
```

Alternative:

```
idx = df.A < 0
res = ['B', 'C']
df.values[idx, df.columns.get_indexer(res)] = 1
print (df)
          A    B    C
0  0.496714  0.0  0.0
1 -0.138264  1.0  0.0
2  0.647689  0.0  0.0
3  1.523030  0.0  0.0
4 -0.234153  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: I feel like there ought to be a way to combine, `df.columns.get_indexer` and `loc`, to go around the recreating the entire dataframe option. Anyway, thanks for the solution, will wait a while before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

```
ind = df.index[idx]
for idx,col in zip(ind,res):
   ...:     df.at[idx,col] = 1

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
          A    B    C
0  0.496714  0.0  0.0
1 -0.138264  1.0  0.0
2  0.647689  0.0  0.0
3  1.523030  0.0  0.0
4 -0.234153  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: avoid for loops within python as much as possible

Comment: I suppose this is an answer, but hoping for something more efficient. +1 none the less.